# QtCreator: how to set parameters for debugging?

Tags: qt, debugging, parameters, arguments, qt-creator

In QtCreator, I have not been able to find how to set the arguments to pass to the executable when running in debug mode.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In QtCreator 2.6.2 it should be:

- Go to Tab called "Projects" just under "Debug",
- Now you have to choose kit with your Qt version (if your IDE is configured properly),
- After selecting kit, you should click tab called "Running", and there should be label with your executable path, **arguments to pass** and working directory.

Comment: The layout has changed in newer versions. In Qt Creator 4.14 this is still in "Projects", but moved to "Build & Run" > Qt Version > "Run" > "Command line arguments"