# How to link QT to VSC ( on mac)

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-code, qt-creator

I'm new to c++ and started a virtual internship EA provides at forage platform to understand how real code actually is. The task is to change the workings of pac-man, [source code](https://github.com/dzui42unit/pacman). It required Qt framework so I installed it and included it's path in VSC but still VSC shows [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dU7u.jpg). I even tried to run the code on Qt Creator it doesn't end up running the [game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQ7ml.png).

Comment: In VSCode you should use CMake and the CMake tools extension. You can't compile Qt based code by just specifying the include directory.

Comment: The Qt creator problem is a user error. The code compiled correctly and even ran however the program requires a command line argument specifying a file name when run. The program tells you that and shows you how you would execute it from the command line. This question should help with that: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16984793/qtcreator-how-to-set-parameters-for-debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16984793/qtcreator-how-to-set-parameters-for-debugging)